# Tridion 2013 Bundle publish minor reserved state items

Tags: publishing, 2013, workflow, bundles

The publisher isn't able to resolve a reserved minor version component.
The component meets the approval status and includeworkflow is marked true.
I expect it to publish with a dynamic ct. The same component publishes with the ct, when it becomes a major version.I'll paste the code soon, as I don't have access to it now. Anything wrong with this conceptually?

Comment: How are you publishing the minor version component ? Is this a part of workflow automatic activity step or publishing manually?

Comment: I've gotten a confirmation from customer support, that they see the same issue and RnD will be consulted.

Comment: FYI - There is a hotfix available for this issue, thanks to R&D and support to provide the fix.

Comment: Good to hear. Could you please add the hotfix details, so it will be helpful for other? link to hotfix or hotfix number would be great.

Comment: Sure Ram. The hotfix number is TT86104. Its basically replacing the DLL Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.dll. The instructions on how to deploy are with the hotfix delivered. Not sure of the location where its uploaded. Support can provide that info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In order to publish a minor version (your item is not in reserved state anymore since it is already locked by a workflow) you should meet the following requirements.

- Your item (bundle) has reached at least the minimal approval status configured in the publication target you are using.
- You have set up IncludeWorkflow flag to true.
- Publishing operations are asynchronous, having said that, you don't know for sure when they will be executed since they are queued in the publishing queue. If your activity is setting the approval status and not a previous activity you should finish the activity first and then publish.

You should make sure that your bundle has the approval status before you publish

```
CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, new ActivityFinishData() {
    Message = FinishMessage,
    NextAssignee = NextAssignee != null ? new LinkToTrusteeData() { IdRef = NextAssignee.Id } : null
}, ReadOptions);

CoreServiceClient.Publish(itemsToPublish, PublishInstruction, publicationTargets, Priority, ReadOptions);
```

Comment: The owner of the changes and activity also mattered at least for 2011 (see [explanation on Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43306/15311)). Is this the same for 2013 (i.e. when minor changes are made by someone else)?

Comment: By default the items published via Workflow are published using the NT Authority account.

Comment: Eric - Thanks for checking on this particular issue :) .. atleast now we can regenerate the issue

Comment: It seems that Bundle.GetItems() is not returning New items during the resolving phase.

Answer (score 2):

If you publish manually it always publish the major version. To publish the minor version you could add an automated task (use assembly or c# code) to publish the minor item.

Check these links :

http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/tutorials/setting-up-bundle-workflow.aspx

http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/12/quick-review-for-tridion-2013-workflow.html (check the `Publish Activity` code snippedt)

Comment: Hi Ram - I'm publishing  the bundle through an external activity which has include workflow set to true.

Comment: you mean the automatic activity? It would be helpful if you could explain the workflow process and the code.

Comment: Hi Ram - The process is simple here.. Create a Bundle and a minor version component. Add it to the Bundle. Create a minor version page. Add that minor version component to the page as a CP via browsing the Bundle. And add the page to the same Bundle. Start workflow on the Bundle and Publish the bundle to a target meeting the approval status usign an external activity, does not publish the page neither the component with a dynamic CT. hope this explains the problem statement in detail.