# Minor Version not Published in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

When I make a change in XPM, to a Workflow enabled item, I would expect the edited (minor version to be republished)

However, I see that only the last major version seems to be automatically published

Then I am continually presented with the `Update Preview` requests and the content within the CME and that on the staging website do not match

I did notice this post [Can you get experience manager to publish minor revisions? (items in workflow)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/10946/can-you-get-experience-manager-to-publish-minor-revisions-items-in-workflow), but I was hoping for something OOTB

If I manually override the publish to include the in-workflow version then `Update Preview` message is removed

Answer (score 1):

The feature to publish item in workflow was added in web 8, look at the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-89F4F890-7095-41CD-9430-B44F0E3230DF#docid=GUID-6CD6BA02-3BB6-4CFD-B4B1-3E3DECB09A66&filename=GUID-6CD6BA02-3BB6-4CFD-B4B1-3E3DECB09A66.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6CD6BA02-3BB6-4CFD-B4B1-3E3DECB09A66)

So I am really doubtful if that functionality is available OOTB on 2013-sp1-hr1. So only option left with you is to do the customization suggested in other article.

Comment: "If possible, publish the in-workflow version of an item" was available in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 (HR1 at least)

Answer (score -1):

If you publish manually it always publishes the major version. To publish the minor version you could add an automated task (use assembly or C# code) to publish the minor item.

Check these links:

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/setting-up-sdl-tridion-multi-item-workflow-with-bundles

http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/12/quick-review-for-tridion-2013-workflow.html (check the Publish Activity code snippet)