# Is Publish Triggered by Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager, event-system, 2013-sp1-hr1

I am wondering if there are any indicators I can use within the following Event System code to know whether the Publish Transaction was triggered by XPM vs. a user?

The only things I've found (which are not conclusive at all) is Component being published to Staging

```
private void SetInWorkflowPublishFlag(IdentifiableObject subject, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
   //TODO: Review if can determine if initiated by XPM vs. Person
   if (args.Targets.Count() == 1 && args.Targets.First().Title.ToLower().Contains("staging"))
   {
      if(subject is Component)
         args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeWorkflow = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: There might be something in the ContextData dictionary. I know you'll find stuff in there like if it's an action caused by Content Porter or Translation Manager. Do not know if we had Experience Manager/CME identified already in 2013 though.

Comment: I tried the ContextData, it was empty

Comment: Sorry. Might have been added in 8.1 only then.